# Anonymous CLOS Instances

Tags: common-lisp, anonymous-class

Is there a vernacular, in Common Lisp, for defining Anonymous Classes in the manner in which one might in Java, for one-off 'small interface implementors'?

For instance,

```
this.addListener(new Listener() {
    public void listen() {...}
});
```

as:

```
(defgeneric listen (object))

(add-listener #<this>
  (make-anonymous-instance
    (listen (object) ...)))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Common Lisp methods belong to generic functions, not classes, therefore anonymous instances don't really make sense. Similar purposes can be achieved, depending on specific circumstances, trough closures or EQL specializers.

Extended in response to comment:

In CL defining methods not at top-level is possible, but not really a good idea. I would suggest just adding the method normally, possibly EQL specialized on a symbol or other constant if no actual instance is needed.

If defining behaviour inline is useful more often than not then it indicates that the interface is misdesigned and should take a closure and not an object. If you cannot fix the interface itself then you could define a class which only purpose is to wrap a closure and add a method calling that closure, then just make an instance with appropriate behaviour slotted.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, so thanks. I understand the relation of methods to generic functions. If in the original example, the instance represented by '#<this>' will invoke the generic function 'listen on listeners added by 'add-listener, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

NOt really. Though with the MOP and some macrology it might be possible.

In the early phase of the development of CLOS there was something like `GENERIC-FLET` proposed. But it did not make it into the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous classes in Java are almost always used to implement anonymous functions and closures. In common lisp, there is no need to emulate Java's anonymous inner classes since function is a first-class type in Common Lisp.

If this is the case, then the code in Common Lisp would look like:

```
(add-listener self (lambda (object) ...))
```